# TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined, js engine: hermes RN 0.64.2

Tags: react-native, react-native-hermes

I've been trying to install a different version but my app keeps on crashing and when I install the latest version I get this error after a successful build

```
LOG  Running "main" with {"rootTag":1}
ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined, js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
```

RN 0.64.2

Answer (score 1):

maybe you don't enable the herms properly. [go to the link, and make sure to clean your .gradle](https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes)

if still faces the issue, so at a cost of little performance effect you can simple disable Herms.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I've found the issue. I am using `react-native-render-html` and I updated that package too. Downgraded the package version to `^5.1.1` and now this is working fine. Seems like latest version of the `react-native-render-html` is not supporting with my current hermes configurations.